# How can I access path variables in my custom HandlerMethodArgumentResolver

Tags: java, spring-mvc

considering this spring MVC handler method:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/profile/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String displayProfile(Person person, ModelMap model) { ... }
```

my question: can I access the value of `id` in this resolver without having to parse the URl manually:

```
public class PersonReslover implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver { .. }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using NativeWebRequest reference, which is accessible from resolveArgument() method of HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.

For example:

```
 private Map<String, String> getPathVariables(NativeWebRequest webRequest) {

    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = webRequest.getNativeRequest(HttpServletRequest.class);
    return (Map<String, String>) httpServletRequest.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);
}
```